# Traveling Europe from US on valid Schengen visa and expired US visa

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork

I will be traveling from Seattle, US to Amsterdam with a layover at Reykjavik with Iceland Air. After a few days in Europe I will be travelling onward to India. I have a valid Indian passport and valid Schengen visa. But the US Visa stamped on my passport has expired. Will there be any problem for this travel?

Just to clarify, I haven't overstayed in US. It's just that the US visa stamped on my passport has expired. I got my visa renewed in the US and have valid docs for it. Just that the renewed visa hasn't been stamped on my passport yet. I will get it stamped once I visit my home country after visiting Europe.

Comment: Will your US visa expire after you have left the US (but before you arrive in Europa) or have you overstayed in the  US for a longer period of time?

Comment: @TheEspinosa That's irrelevant

Comment: @Coke That's not entirely irrelevant. OP might be stopped by CBP when boarding the plane. While there is no general "exit passport control" when leaving the US, random checks are possible. Should OP have overstayed, then this will be an issue.

Comment: @markusju An expired US visa and having overstayed are two entirely different things.  You can overstay within the validity of the visa, and have a one-time entry visa which allows you to stay for an indefinite time.

Comment: I do not think from the question that the OP has overstayed. But if he has and the European immigration officer finds out (there might still be an interview), he might (worst case scenario) have doubts that the OP will leave Schengen area in time.

Comment: @markusju You're not an overstayer just because your visa's expired

Comment: Just to clarify, I haven't overstayed in US. It's just that the US visa stamped on my passport has expired. I got my visa renewed in the US and have valid docs for it. Just that the renewed visa hasn't been stamped on my passport yet. I will get it stamped once I visit my home country after visiting Europe.

Comment: The visa expiration date should be irrelevant. You can have an expired visa, not try to renew it and still be in the US legally. Visa is just a document that allows you to approach a point of entry, not actually enter (visa does not guarantee getting an i94 for example). I have an expired visa in my passport, but i also have a green card. When i just hand my passport to some airline officials, they ask if i have a green card. In your case you might be able to show some document that explains that your visa has been renewed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a valid Schengen visa, which means you can enter the Schengen Area. You will clear immigration in Reykjavik, and then catch a "domestic" flight to Amsterdam, without border checks.

Comment: This has the usual proviso that a visa is never a cast-iron guarantee of entry.

Answer (score 4):

Europe is going to be least bothered about the status of your US Visa. With your Schengen visa you're good to go to Amsterdam and Reykjavik.

Comment: OP will clear immigration in Iceland, not Amsterdam, but yes, a Schengen visa can, in principle, be used to enter Schengen anywhere

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have any problems unless you try to return to the US with that expired visa.

In which case you're likely to be denied boarding at the very least on your flight to the US.

Comment: Yes that's right. I won't be entering on expired visa.